# Angular snack bar increasing z-index not working?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

**Scenario :**

- I have a Bootstrap Modal opened.
- While user interacting with the modal , if any error occurs, I would
  like to show that error in Angular Snack bar.
- Snack bar is shown
  behind Bootstrap modal. And I would like Angular snack bar to be
  shown in front on screen and Bootstrap modal behind.

It is possible
   by changing any css-z-index things ?

Comment: Can you please include more details or your current implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Again, **[RTFM](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api#MatSnackBarConfig)** !

```
panelClass: string | string[]         Extra CSS classes to be added to the snack bar container.
```

Provide this as the config to your snackbar (or override the provider in your own module to apply it to every snackbar), and set the z-index in your given class.

Answer (score 0):

all of them is working for me.

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container {
  z-index: 10000 !important;
}
```

or

```
.cdk-overlay-container {
    z-index: 99999999999999; 
}
```

or

```
:host /deep/ .cdk-overlay-pane{
   z-index: 1000;
 }
```